# Use asp.net identity in business layer and add properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am creating finance app. I'm using asp.net identity. When a user logs in they'll just see their company's records. I have GetRecords(int userID) it returns all records for user's company.

```
public List<FinanceData> GetRecords(int userID){
       int companyID = userService.GetCompanyID(userID);
       financeService.GetFinanceData(companyID);
 }
```

My questions are:

1- In asp.net mvc layer I can reach User.Identity.Name but business layer (class lib.) I can't reach this data property. How can reach this?

2- Can I add properties like User.Identity.CompanyID and how can I fill it when user logs in. Because I don't want to go the database for each request.

I want to use my method like this:

```
public List<FinanceData> GetRecords(){
         financeService.GetFinanceData(User.Identity.CompanyID);
     }
```

Comment: There's no way to achieve this without hitting the database. Only certain user details are pulled by authentication. Something like `CompanyID` would need to be queried each time. Even using claims involves querying the database again to get the claims.

Comment: @ChrisPratt that's not true

Comment: Sorry, but it is. They're actually stored in the database and there's Identity extensions for Entity Framework to retrieve them from the database. Use something like Glimpse to monitor the queries being issued to the database when you use claims. You'll see queries come up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asp.net identity uses Claims to store user information, this model is very flexible and you can totally add custom claims to it, like CompanyId. You would have to implement that in your `ApplicationUser` or where ever the ClaimsIdentity gets created and add your custom claims to it.

(following code is copied from the MVC template)

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // **Add custom user claims here**
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

Then ClaimsPrincipal will be available via `Thread.CurrentPrinciapl` everywhere in your app which is running in the same AppDomain. So if your other layer is not running as a service somewhere else, you can totally use

```
var principal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal as ClaimsPrincipal
```

check if this is not null and if it is authenticated, and you should be good to go.

To make it even more convenient you can write extension methods for the ClaimsPrincipal for `.CompanyId` for example.

Comment: Claims *can* be used to store additional user information, but in practice, I don't think it's a good approach. Since the actual user object is extensible in Identity, you're better off just adding additional properties to it. The only information I store in user claims are transient like a Facebook auth token - something that doesn't apply to every user, doesn't need to be exposed for editing (such as in a user profile view) and which may have a determined "lifetime" or staleness factor.

Comment: Well you can store everything in the claim which you do not want to query from the database every time. So that you can work with the currently authenticated user without retrieving the additional information again and again in all layers of your app. We use it for storing roles for example, which is pretty convenient. Of course you should not store everything in there... all that data might end up in a cookie, if you use cookie auth ^^

Comment: Umm... Nope. Not sure what you think is happening with claims, but they are queried from the database each time you hit them. They are not somehow stored between requests.

Comment: Nope they are not queried from the database every time, that's what claims are for right? Should store simple user information along with the secured "session". So if you use cookie auth for example, as long as the cookie is valid and every request in your web site gets the cookie, that cookie will be the source of the user's data, and the database will only be hit for checking the validation token for example. You can easily test this by creating an empty MVC 5 page with the generated login etc... and put a breakpoint in `GenerateUserIdentityAsync` and see how often that guy gets invoked